# Is there a way with sox to trim parts of audio file with volume under a certain level?

Tags: sound, files, output, editing, sox

I have an audio file and I want to delete the parts of this audio file that have less than a certain level of volume. Is that possible with sox?

Answer (score 1):

[Sox documentation:](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html)

example

```
sox input.wav output.wav silence 1 0.1 1% -1 0.1 1%
```